# Why is kerosene used in Aviation industry for turbogas and turboprop?

Tags: fuel

Which are advantages (and disadvantages) compared to gasoline or petroil?

Comment: Putting 100LL or 100UL in a turboprop is a good way to blow it up. Putting Jet-A in a piston engine is a good way to keep it from running, typically during take-off. Different fuels have different properties that are matched to the type of combustion that they perform.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- 100LL in a turbine *can* be tolerated under some conditions (most smaller gas turbines can digest it AFAIK).  However, Jet-A really makes spark-ignition engines unhappy campers!